# Python unit test @mock.patch set mock property

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Is there a way to have class patches with mocked properties set in once place? Say I have the following class I want to test.

```
class ExampleClass
    def __init__(self, specific_args):
        # Do something with specific args
        self.specific_args = specific_args
        self.sub_component = SubComponent(...)

    def example_function_double_value(self) -> float:
        return SomeFunction(self.specific_args, self.sub_component.value)
```

and it has the following unit test where I patch out `SubComponent` and set `SubComponent.value` to return 3.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

def set_patch(patch: mock.Mock):
    patch_return_value = mock.Mock()
    patch_return_value.value = 3
    patch.return_value = patch_return_value

@mock.patch('SubComponent_Path.SubComponent')
class ExampleUnitTest(unittest.TestCase)

    def test_case1(self, patch):
        set_patch(patch)
        specific_args1 = # Generate specific arguments for this test case
        test_class = ExampleClass(specfic_args1)

        # Some assertion where I expect `subcomponent.value to be 3`

    def test_case2(self, patch):
        set_patch(patch)
        specific_args2 = # Generate specific arguments for this test case
        test_class = ExampleClass(specfic_args2)

        # Some other assertion where I expect `subcomponent.value to be 3`
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without needing to call that helper function at the start of each test?

Comment: Define `def __init__(self, factory=SubComponent): self.sub_component = factory()`, and you don't need `mock.patch` at all.

Comment: This is simplified skeleton code, while that makes a lot of sense for this example, I can't do that (make the component a constructor arg and pass in a mock) for my code :(

Comment: Why not? It's one additional keyword argument with a default, which means you don't have to change *anything* else that uses your class.